# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

We have created a web app to upload and view 3D models. The models are being uploaded successfully, but we are facing an issue on viewing models.

We are getting the error “Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)”.

We can view recent uploaded files on same server but we have a problem with old uploaded files on another server.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: 401 unauthorized means invalid or missing user/password. Check your credentials.

Comment: Hello @Alejandro, actually the credentials are right as I can view recent uploaded files but I have a problem with old uploaded files.

Comment: Since the server says that the credentials are wrong probably some change has happened in between. Can you post the (relevant) code that generates the 401 error?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you use the same APS app credentials (client_secret and client_id) used to upload the files. Using new app credentials to view files created with different APS app credentials will result in 401 (unauthorized).